# What is the most efficient way to find elements in an unsorted list?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

Given an unsorted list in an array, will it necessarily take at least linear time to find the number of elements smaller than x? If so, why?

Comment: This smells like homework. Especially the "If so, why?" part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you would need to examine every number at least once to know if it is less than a specified threshold.  If the numbers are not sorted there is nothing you can infer about them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need at least linear time. There is no way to know whether an element is smaller than x without checking it, so you have to check every element once.

If you sorted it first, then you could stop as soon as an element was greater than x.

Comment: If it is sorted, "stoping as soon as element is greater than x" is also linear. You can get a `O (log n)` time if you do a binary search.

Comment: First, to sort it is `O(n log n)`. Second, given that it is sorted, on average it is still `O(n)` unless you binary search which reduces it to `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing for an unlimited number of processors you can solve the problem in near constant time, assumming concatenating of the results is fast: Just split the array in chunks of fixed size and process each chunk on a separate processor.

If we are talking about a single processor I'd say you need linear time:

- you need to inspect each element and if it fits the predicate put it in the result.
- sorting or similar won't help, because again you have to inspect each element at least once.

Comment: This is still linear time; if you have n processors you must spend linear time allocating the chunks to them and figuring out the overall answer at the end. If you have << n processors then the speedup is only a constant factor (which might still be useful, of course, depending on the scale of the problem etc).